# setTimeout and setInterval on same function(with parameters)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, settimeout, intervals

I want to set a timeout and an Interval as an onmousedown eventhandler for this function.

```
function start(clicked_className,clicked_classValue)
{
      add(clicked_className,clicked_classValue);
}


startInter=setInterval(start.bind(null,y.className, y.value.replace(/\s/g, '')),600);
```

That's what I have as working Interval, but don't know how to add timeout without it being 2 separate things. I want the Interval to have a timeout.

Comment: What is the problem? Also what is the meaning of `start` function being exactly same as `add`?

Comment: I edited post... Its because im testing things and I want to use the add function seperately, for that example it doesnt make a difference

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point at all.. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` **are** two different things, different functions returning different values.. Please clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to print a char multiple times, but after the first one, which happens immediately after mousedown, i want to have a bigger pause than inbetween the ones that come later,like: action->7_______________7__7__7__7__7__7__7__7...

Comment: So when I get your latest comment, the structure has to be something like this..

setTimeout(() => {
  fn(); 
  setIntervall(() => fn(), smallPeriodicalBreakTime);
}, initialBreakTime); ?

Comment: yes that worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put `setInterval` inside `setTimeout` function, something like:

```js
el.onmousedown = function() {
   start(...)
   setTimeout(function(){
      // start(...) // maybe also here?
      setInterval(function(){
         start(...)
      },1000)
   },5000)
}
```

Comment: yes thank you that is the right way... but I cant figure how exactly :(

Comment: then please try to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question (to see where exactly is the problem)

Comment: i did that, the problem was that I simply didnt know how to write the synthax but thanksss=) that helped

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function()
{
setInterval(start.bind(null,y.className, y.value.replace(/\s/g, '')),400);
},1000);
```

worked